# Is it possible to use Firebase's Stripe integration for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, firebase, server, payment

Firebase released an integration with Stripe so that you don't have to build your own server infrastructure. It can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments#what_to_do_with_the_sample_app

The web page specifically says that you can process payments for web apps. But if I am building an iOS app, can I still go about using this integration? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Good question. Don't understand why people downvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js) that in links to shows you how to implement the integration in a way that works across platforms. Stripe is integrated there using Cloud Functions for Firebase. This means it runs on a Google server outside of the client. It can work across iOS, Android, and web. When you write to `/stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}`, the function is triggered and carries out the payment. And yes, you don't have to build your own server. If you aren't familiar with Cloud Functions for Firebase, then check out these resources:

[Cloud Functions for Firebase Usage Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

[Cloud Functions for Firebase samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)

[Getting Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase - Firecasts](https://youtu.be/EvV9Vk9iOCQ)

[Database Triggers with Cloud Functions for Firebase - Firecasts](https://youtu.be/7E13ZBCyKT0)

Comment: Okay awesome. Thanks so much! I had been researching this for a while and could never find a straight answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in the higher-level flow of payments with `Stripe`, the way we used it is as follows -

```
1) iOS/Android provides card details to Stripe using native SDK
2) Stripe provides a token which you send it to your Firebase
3) Firebase cloud function then triggers a function and uses this token to make a payment or create Stripe customer and make payment
4) after you make payment, store required information like amount paid, date etc on Firebase so that ios/Android can list payments on the app
```

Comment: How exactly do you send the token to firebase? I'm trying to use childbyautoid but it doesn't accept parameters. I have read that it behaves the same way as push(), but from the tutorial, push accepts the token as a parameter.